# How to add a music to a new class in Flash?

Tags: flash

How can I add music to a new class in Flash?
It doesn't work for me, see the image below:

[image]

How do I make "Export for ActionScript" selectable?  I can't seem to select the textfield to export...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the `Exporter pour Actionscript` box (small square). That should allow you to edit the textbox with your preferred `Classe` name for controlling later via AS3 code.

This article has good advice for AS3:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't click the Exporter pour Actionscript box

Comment: Did you import the **mp3** to your library? Then right-click to edit **properties**? If its already used on timeline (stage) it might not work...